# How to print out QListWidget labels to strings?

Tags: c++, qt, qstring, qtgui, qlistwidget

I'm making a GUI program that allows user to drag and drop to reorganize items in a list. To do this I am thinking of creating a new vector container of stuff and read from the list after each change to rearrange the container and update it.

So far I had little success on even just printing out what's displayed in the list, i.e., "Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3".

Please help!

Comment: Why would you not like to use models for it?

Answer (score 1):

You would need to iterate through each item and get the text of that as follows:

```
QStringList myStringList;
for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
    myStringList.append(myListWidget.item(i).text());
qDebug() << myStringList;
```